# How to remove yellow border comes around the textbox in Chrome & Safari

Tags: html, css

i have a html page.While i take the page in chrome or Safari , there is a yellow border around the text box.

For removing the border,i have added

```
<style type="text/css">
  input{
  outline:none;
}
</style>
```

And the border has gone.

But while i take the page in Mac machine  (chrome & Safari).it still there.
Anyone have idea of how to fix it in Mac?

Comment: Are you aware of [the issues surrounding this](http://outlinenone.com/)?

Comment: thanks MaVRoSCy.I wil change it to input:focus{}

Answer (score 11):

```
:focus {
  outline: 0;
  outline-color: transparent;
  outline-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting it too no color:

```
.foo:active, .foo:focus {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using bootstrap's CSS, it's likely the culprit. find the problem here:

```
select:focus, input[type="file"]:focus, input[type="radio"]:focus, input[type="checkbox"]:focus {
  outline: thin dotted #333;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

if you cannot edit the bootstap.css use this, works like a charm.

```
select:focus, input:focus, textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  outline-color: transparent;
  outline-style: none;
}
```